# PyCharm: Run single test via tox?

Tags: pycharm, tox

PyCharm: Run single test via tox.

If I run a single test on the commandline it works fine:

```
tox -e py27 mymodule.tests.test_models.FooTests.test_magic
```

But I failed to execute this via the green "play" button (or ctrl-shift-F10)

[image: test_magic]

PyCharm seems to always want to run `_jb_unittest_runner.py`.

Is there a way to run `tox` instead of `_jb_unittest_runner.py`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this.

Note however that you can set the interpreter tox uses (under the path `.tox/py27`) as your project interpreter, and then the unittest/pytest runner would allow you to run the test within PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

- create new tox configuration:

  - run/debug configurations --> add new configuration --> tox
- Arguments:

  - in pycharm 2022 `tests/test_models.py::test_magic`
  - in pycharm 2023.2 `-- tests/test_models.py::test_magic`
- project: mymodule
- Working directory: `/full/path/to/project`
- Add content roots - `enabled`
- Add source roots - `enabled`

..press run button